# search for a string with special characters linux

Tags: regex, awk

I'm new in bash scripting. I am trying to get words from the file which matches some pattern. However, I cannot get anything from it. I think the problem is in special characters. Could someone help me to find a solution.

example:

[image]

my code:

```
awk '/[c8d313c81caa1103:-603ec52f:1630466b4e8:5448][amirbekova] com.sas.analytics.crm.custdata.sql/{flag=1;next}/quit;/{flag=0}flag && /CMDM\./' SASMarketingAutomationCore5.4.log.2018-04-27 >> test1.txt
```

So i'm searching for CMDM. word which is in between patterns:

```
[c8d313c81caa1103:-603ec52f:1630466b4e8:5448][amirbekova] com.sas.analytics.crm.custdata.sql
```

and

```
quit;
```

Input:

```
[c8d313c81caa1103:-603ec52f:1630466b4e8:5448][amirbekova] com.sas.analytics.crm.custdata.sql - TID[25810F8F] \namirbekova----- Execute Sql in MAIQService.execute() ----- \nPROC SQL; \nCreate table MATables.TXIDFAEAIZ5BDSAAGamirbekova as \nSELECT DISTINCT table0.DWH_ID AS DWH_ID LABEL='Идентификатор клиента в КИХ' FORMAT=$40. \nFROM \nCMDM.INDIVIDUAL_OBLIGATIONS table2 Left join CMDM.SYS_DICT_BINARY table1 on ( ( (table2.IO_ACTIVE_SIGN=table1.ID)) ) \nRight join CMDM.CLIENT table0 on ( ( (table0.DWH_ID=table2.CLIENT _DWH_ID)) ) quit;
```

Output:

```
- TID[25810F8F] amirbekova----- Execute Sql in MAIQService.execute() ----- PROC SQL; Create table MATables.TXIDFAEAIZ5BDSAAGamirbekova as SELECT DISTINCT table0.DWH_ID AS DWH_ID LABEL='Идентификатор клиента в КИХ' FORMAT=$40. FROM CMDM.INDIVIDUAL_OBLIGATIONS table2 Left join CMDM.SYS_DICT_BINARY table1 on ( ( (table2.IO_ACTIVE_SIGN=table1.ID)) ) Right join CMDM.CLIENT table0 on ( ( (table0.DWH_ID=table2.CLIENT _DWH_ID)) )
```

Comment: can you add some part of your input file?
input and expected output!

Comment: here it is:

[c8d313c81caa1103:-603ec52f:1630466b4e8:5448][amirbekova] com.sas.analytics.crm.custdata.sql       - TID[25810F8F]
amirbekova----- Execute Sql in MAIQService.execute() -----

PROC SQL;
Create table MATables.TXIDFAEAIZ5BDSAAGamirbekova as
SELECT  DISTINCT
        table0.DWH_ID AS DWH_ID LABEL='Идентификатор клиента в КИХ' FORMAT=$40.
FROM
        CMDM.INDIVIDUAL_OBLIGATIONS table2 Left join CMDM.SYS_DICT_BINARY table1 on  ( ( (table2.IO_ACTIVE_SIGN=table1.ID)) )  Right join CMDM.CLIENT table0 on  ( ( (table0.DWH_ID=table2.CLIENT
_DWH_ID)) )
quit;

Comment: expected output is a line which contains word CMDM or everything between those two patterns

Comment: @Oljas Edit your sample input/output into your question, don't hide it down here in the comments. You can't use (most) formatting here so it's hard to read.

Comment: sorry, I got it. is that ok now? I have multiple lines which contains this pattern

Comment: Is your input all on one line?

Comment: added example pic

Comment: Don't use the words `pattern` or `special` as they are both highly ambiguous. Figure out if you're talking about a regexp, a string, a condition, a regexp metachar, a globbing char or whatever else it is you really mean in each case and use that term instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run the following `grep` command on your file/variable.

```
grep -oP '(?<=\[c8d313c81caa1103:-603ec52f:1630466b4e8:5448]\[amirbekova] com\.sas\.analytics\.crm\.custdata\.sql)(.*)(?=quit;)' ~/test_awk/input_file
```

**Explanations:**

- `-oP` `-o` to display as output just the matching regex and not the whole line and `-P` to activate the perl regex for lookbehind/lookahead,...
- the following regex `(?<=\[c8d313c81caa1103:-603ec52f:1630466b4e8:5448]\[amirbekova] com\.sas\.analytics\.crm\.custdata\.sql)(.*)(?=quit;)` to match your pattern: demo: https://regex101.com/r/FFrCu3/1/ and 
  explanations about the regex: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

**DEMO:**

```
$ cat ~/test_awk/input_file
[c8d313c81caa1103:-603ec52f:1630466b4e8:5448][amirbekova] com.sas.analytics.crm.custdata.sql - TID[25810F8F] amirbekova----- Execute Sql in MAIQService.execute() ----- PROC SQL; Create table MATables.TXIDFAEAIZ5BDSAAGamirbekova as SELECT DISTINCT table0.DWH_ID AS DWH_ID LABEL='Идентификатор клиента в КИХ' FORMAT=$40. FROM CMDM.INDIVIDUAL_OBLIGATIONS table2 Left join CMDM.SYS_DICT_BINARY table1 on ( ( (table2.IO_ACTIVE_SIGN=table1.ID)) ) Right join CMDM.CLIENT table0 on ( ( (table0.DWH_ID=table2.CLIENT _DWH_ID)) ) quit;

$ grep -oP '(?<=\[c8d313c81caa1103:-603ec52f:1630466b4e8:5448]\[amirbekova] com\.sas\.analytics\.crm\.custdata\.sql)(.*)(?=quit;)' ~/test_awk/input_file
 - TID[25810F8F] amirbekova----- Execute Sql in MAIQService.execute() ----- PROC SQL; Create table MATables.TXIDFAEAIZ5BDSAAGamirbekova as SELECT DISTINCT table0.DWH_ID AS DWH_ID LABEL='Идентификатор клиента в КИХ' FORMAT=$40. FROM CMDM.INDIVIDUAL_OBLIGATIONS table2 Left join CMDM.SYS_DICT_BINARY table1 on ( ( (table2.IO_ACTIVE_SIGN=table1.ID)) ) Right join CMDM.CLIENT table0 on ( ( (table0.DWH_ID=table2.CLIENT _DWH_ID)) )
```

If your pattern is on several lines then you can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk '/^\[c8d313c81caa1103:-603ec52f:1630466b4e8:5448\]\[amirbekova\] com.sas.analytics.crm.custdata.sql/{flag=1;print $NF;next}/^quit;/{flag=0;}{if(flag){print}}' input_file
```

Comment: Allan, will this code work if there is a whitespace between<br>
[c8d313c81caa1103:-603ec52f:1630466b4e8:5448]  
[amirbekova]?

Comment: @Oljas: if your pattern is on several lines it will not work... Let me fix that

Comment: Allan, I mean I have a whitespace between two square brackets. Is that a case that the code is not working?

Comment: @Oljas: you can change your awk command in:

`awk '/^\[c8d313c81caa1103:-603ec52f:1630466b4e8:5448\]\s+\[amirbekova\] com.sas.analytics.crm.custdata.sql/{flag=1;print $NF;next}/^quit;/{flag=0;}{if(flag){print}}' input_file` to take into account the spaces

Comment: wrt your comment, you should mention that `\s` is GNU awk only.

Answer (score 0):

`[` and `]` are special in regexes and need to be escaped: `\[`

Same for the dots in your first pattern: `com\.sas\.`, etc.

Comment: @Oljas "*did not work*" is not a problem description. See [mcve].

Comment: Is it correct?

awk '/\\[c8d313c81caa1103:-603ec52f:1630466b4e8:5448\\]\\[amirbekova\\] com\.sas\.analytics\.crm\.custdata.sql/{flag=1;next}/quit;/{flag=0}flag && /CMDM\./' SASMarketingAutomationCore5.4.log.2018-04-27 >> test1.txt

Comment: @Oljas Your comment keeps changing. Please post code as code so I can see what you're actually doing.